# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S' in xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

**Python version:** 3.8.1

**xlrd**:1.2.0

**Format**: .xlsx

I am getting the below error message while trying to create an object for an excel.

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'**

**Source code:- Sample**

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

class Excellibrary():
    _activesheet = ""
    _filepath = ""

def open_excelsheet(self, filepath):

    Excellibrary._filepath = filepath
    Excellibrary._activesheet = open_workbook(filepath)

run=Excellibrary()
run.open_excelsheet(filepath)
```

**Traceback:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo\boo\Excellibrary.py", line 117, in <module>
    run.open_excelsheet(
  File "foo\boo\Excellibrary.py", line 14, in open_desired_excel
    ExcelOperations._activesheet = open_workbook(filepath)
  File "foo\boo\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 130, in open_workbook
    bk = xlsx.open_workbook_2007_xml(
  File "foo\boo\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 841, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
  File "foo\boo\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 553, in own_process_stream
    self.do_dimension(elem)
  File "foo\boo\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 601, in do_dimension
    rowx, colx = cell_name_to_rowx_colx(
  File "foo\boo\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 113, in cell_name_to_rowx_colx
    rowx = int(cell_name[charx:]) - 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'
```

I am able to create an object for the same excel only when it is opened and saved(NO edit) manually. The file does not contain any formulas or macros in it. I am NOT sure how come it works ONLY when excel is saved with absolutely no changes.

Could anyone help me where does the issue probably exists?

Note: Due to security reasons, I can't share the original excel file.

Comment: It is quite hard to tell without looking at the excel file, but from looking at `xlsx` it seems as if there is a label/range of the form `A1S` or `C3:4S` or something like that somewhere in your excel file. When parsing a range, `xlsx` found an instance where an `S` follows a digit instead of the other way round.